# Snowflake -WITH RECURSIVE... is too long and would be truncated in 'CONCAT'

Tags: concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

Something aparently as easy as the following query is driving me crazy, anyone can help?

```
SELECT * FROM 
             (
                          WITH recursive colores (id_modelo, cod_color, rango) AS
                          (
                                 SELECT id_modelo,
                                        cod_color,
                                        rango
                                 FROM   dwh_vse.dwh_colores_orden_v
                                 WHERE  rango = 1
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT a.id_modelo,
                                        c.cod_color
                                               || '-'
                                               ||a.cod_color,
                                        a.rango
                                 FROM   dwh_vse.dwh_colores_orden_v a,
                                        colores c
                                 WHERE  a.id_modelo = c.id_modelo
                                 AND    a.rango = c.rango+1 )
                   SELECT   id_modelo,
                   Max(cod_color)AS cod_color_agr
                   FROM     colores
                   GROUP BY id_modelo
             )


**ERROR:
String '01-11-23' is too long and would be truncated in 'CONCAT'**

--Trying with: TRY_CAST(cod_color AS varchar(100))

SELECT * FROM 
             (
                          WITH recursive colores (id_modelo, cod_color, rango) AS
                          (
                                 SELECT id_modelo,
                                        TRY_CAST(cod_color AS varchar(100)) AS cod_color,
                                        rango
                                 FROM   dwh_vse.dwh_colores_orden_v
                                 WHERE  rango = 1
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT a.id_modelo,
                                        c.cod_color
                                               || '-'
                                               ||a.cod_color,
                                        a.rango
                                 FROM   dwh_vse.dwh_colores_orden_v a,
                                        colores c
                                 WHERE  a.id_modelo = c.id_modelo
                                 AND    a.rango = c.rango+1 )
                   SELECT   id_modelo,
                   Max(cod_color)AS cod_color_agr
                   FROM     colores
                   GROUP BY id_modelo
             )


**SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300010:2265280747; incident 3211946.**


--CAST(cod_color as string) 
SELECT * FROM 
             (
                          WITH recursive colores (id_modelo, cod_color, rango) AS
                          (
                                 SELECT id_modelo,
                                        CAST(cod_color as string) AS cod_color,
                                        rango
                                 FROM   dwh_vse.dwh_colores_orden_v
                                 WHERE  rango = 1
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT a.id_modelo,
                                        c.cod_color
                                               || '-'
                                               ||a.cod_color,
                                        a.rango
                                 FROM   dwh_vse.dwh_colores_orden_v a,
                                        colores c
                                 WHERE  a.id_modelo = c.id_modelo
                                 AND    a.rango = c.rango+1 )
                   SELECT   id_modelo,
                   Max(cod_color)AS cod_color_agr
                   FROM     colores
                   GROUP BY id_modelo
             )

**SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300010:2265280747; incident 1742159.**
```

The recursive on cod_color should give somenthing for instance like '01-11-23'
I have others querys with recursive and with fields on the recursive longer than in this case (VARCHAR(2)) and I don´t get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem taking into account the size of the field of the source table.
Must be large enough to contain the concatenation.
For this particular case
dwh_vse.dwh_colores_orden
COD_COLOR VARCHAR(250)